# Using sizeof() on malloc'd memory

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [newbie questions about malloc and sizeof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533519/newbie-questions-about-malloc-and-sizeof)

I am trying to read strings into a program. When I noticed that the strings were sometimes being corrupted, I tried the following code:

```
 void *mallocated = malloc(100);
 printf("sizeof(mallocated) = %d\n", sizeof(mallocated));
```

According to my program, the size of `mallocated` was `8`, even though I allocated 100 bytes for it. Because of this, whenever I try to store a string longer than 8 bytes, everything after the 8th byte will sometimes disappear. Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: sizeof(mallocated) will give you the size of void* which is 8 bytes on your 64-bit system. How do you assign a string to that variable, with strcpy?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533519/newbie-questions-about-malloc-and-sizeof

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong too, anything written after the 8th "byte" (not bit) doesn't randomly dissapear sometimes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the size of the "string" pointer is 8 bytes. Here are some examples of using `sizeof()` with their appropriate "size". The term `size_of()` is sometimes deceiving for people not used to using it. In your case, the size of the pointer is 8 bytes.. below is a representation on a typical 32-bit system.

```
sizeof (char)   = 1
sizeof (double) = 8
sizeof (float)  = 4
sizeof (int)    = 4
sizeof (long)   = 4
sizeof (long long)  = 8
sizeof (short)  = 2
sizeof (void *) = 4

sizeof (clock_t)    = 4
sizeof (pid_t)  = 4
sizeof (size_t) = 4
sizeof (ssize_t)    = 4
sizeof (time_t) = 4
```

[Source](http://www.pccl.demon.co.uk/C/sizeof.html)

You are leaving out how you are determining your string is disappearing (char array). It is probably being passed to a function, which you need to pass the explicit length as a variable or track it somewhere. Using `sizeof()` won't tell you this.

See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051462/question-about-why-string-is-truncated-on-first-instance-of-0) about this and you'll see even my lack of initial understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem with the program wasn't quite what I thought it was (is it ever?) but your advice was very useful.

Answer (score 15):

In C89, `sizeof` operator only finds the size of a *variable* in bytes at compile time (in this case a `void` pointer of 8 bytes). It works the way you'd expect it to work on plain arrays, because their size is known at compile time.

```
char arr[100]; // sizeof arr == 100
char *p = arr; // sizeof p == 4 (or 8 on 64-bit architectures)
char *p = malloc(100); // sizeof p == 4 (or 8). Still!
```

To know the size of heap-allocated memory, you need to keep track of it manually, `sizeof` won't help you.

Comment: That's not true. In C99, `sizeof` returns the size of a variable length array, which in many cases can only be determined at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, I excluded C99 case from the answer to keep things simpler.

Answer (score 9):

`sizeof` returns the size of the pointer (`void *`) that you gave it, not the size of the memory you allocated. You would have to store the size of the memory in a separate variable if you want to use it later.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. As pointed out, you can get the size of the `void *` mallocated, but that does not tell you much.

You **cannot** get the size of the malloed `*mallocated`. That is to say, there is no function call to return 100 (in your example) - unless you write your own memory management routines.

Simplest is just to remember it somewhere ... maybe ....

```
stuct {
  void *data;
  unsigned int size
 } myStructureWhichRemebersItsSize;

myStructureWhichRemebersItsSize *someData;
someData.data = malloc(100);  // and check for NULL
someData.size = 100;
```

Comment: "You cannot get the size of the malloed"... Not true, it depends on your C libraries.  Under MS's CRT STDLIB, you can simply call `_msize(*mallocated)` to get the "100" that the OP seeks.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info. I don't use MS, so did not know that. A useful feature that would be nice to see in more places. Of course, behind the scenes the compiler is probably generating a structure such as I describe.

Comment: if **someData** is declared to be a pointer you have to access its fields using the '->' operator

Answer (score -1):

`void*` is the type of a location in memory if you don't know what it contains. It should be avoided.

`char*` is the type of a value which points to some location in memory which holds a `char`. Identifying a location in memory takes eight bytes.

`sizeof` tells you how many bytes a particular type takes. Not how many were allocated with `malloc` but just how much memory compiler knows the type *should* take. Applying `sizeof` to values is often considered bad style, and as someone else mentioned here, sometimes invokes smart behavior in C99.

`char[100]` the type of a value which holds 100 chars. `char[100] a;` is a string of 100 `char`s on the stack.

`char(*)[100]` is the type of a pointer to a value that holds 100 chars. `char(*b)[100];` makes `b` point to 100 chars, possibly on the heap. What you probably want is

```
char (*s)[100] = malloc( sizeof( char[100] ) );
printf( "%u byte pointer to %u bytes of size %u elements\n",
  sizeof s, sizeof *s, sizeof **s );
```