# Errors when making a dynamic C array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I have a struct called `Collection`:

```
typedef struct collection {
   char *type;
   char *arg;
} *Collection;
```

And I would like to have a dynamic array of this struct (or rather, of pointers to instances of this struct). This is what I tried:

```
Collection *rawCollections = malloc(0);
int colCounter = 0;
while (i < argc) {
    Collection col = malloc(sizeof(Collection));
    // code to fill in Collection
    rawCollections = realloc(rawCollections, sizeof(rawCollections) + sizeof(Collection));
    rawCollections[colCounter] = col;
    colCounter++;
}
```

My reasoning is that we will add `sizeof(Collection)` to the array each time I need to add another one. I am getting these errors, and I am not sure why:

```
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: `sizeof(rawCollections)` [does not change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2259890/11683).

Comment: You need to keep your own counter for the size to reallocate (for example `colCounter`).

Comment: Do not hide pointer nature behind a typedef.  It confuses everyone, including you.

Comment: `Collection col = malloc(sizeof(Collection));` is also wrong.

Comment: @user3121023 that's supposed to say `rawCollections` -> fixed now

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's what our prof wants us to use unfortunately

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Can you elaborate? That part seems to work fine.

Comment: `Collection` is a typedef of `struct collection *`.  So you are creating a variable of type `struct collection *` and pointing it to memory allocated to be the size of `struct collection *`.  That is, you allocated the size of a pointer when you should have allocated the size of the object being pointed to.  You can fix that by turning the `malloc` call into `malloc(sizeof(*col))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must compute the new size for the array by multiplying the size of the array element (a pointer to a `struct collection`) by the new number of elements (`colCounter + 1`).

Note also how confusing it is to hide pointers behind typedefs: `sizeof(Collection)` is **not** the size of the structure.

Here is a modified version:

```
struct collection **rawCollections = NULL;  // no need for `malloc(0)`
int colCounter = 0;
while (i < argc) {
    struct collection *col = malloc(sizeof(*col));
    // code to fill in Collection
    rawCollections = realloc(rawCollections, sizeof(*rawCollections) * (colCounter + 1));
    rawCollections[colCounter] = col;
    colCounter++;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(Collection)` is the size of the pointer to the structure, correct?

Comment: @shurup: yes it is, but you write `Collection col = malloc(sizeof(Collection));` which is incorrect: you should allocate the space for a structure, not the space for a pointer.